# wso2 calling API's without token

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am managing my APIs using WSO2 API Mananger.Till now every API were private and can be accessed using an access token.
The new use cases some API's which is purely public. Any one can access them anonymously. Just a GET,POST,PUT wihtout any token/access details should work.

I exposed API's via WSO2 API Manager without any scopes. Tried to access them without any token ;but its not working.It says required oAuth credentails not found.
Is there anything else to do to expose APIs so that they are accessible anonymously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `Manage` page of publisher, you can set `Authentication Type` to `None` for each resource instead of the default value `Application and Application User`.

Comment: Thanks. it works. Can you tell me what is the difference between Application and application user?

Comment: This specifies what kind of tokens you want to accept. Application-wide (subscriber creates a token for her application and then the API will just know that the calls are coming from that app) or User-specific (when each end-user of that application - for example, a mobile app user scenario - will be getting a separate individual token even though the app was created by a shared Subscriber - and thus the backend will know from JWT token who is calling).

P.S. You should really ask questions like that as a separate topic and not in comments. :)

Comment: Adding to @DSotnikov's answer, basically the tokens generated by client credentials grant type, which doesn't require user credentials, comes under "Application Type".

Comment: See the blog post for details: http://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/oauth-and-authentication-type-application-vs-application-user/