# WSO2 API Manager- Can we access API without access token / subscription?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is this possible to access API without subscription / without access token in WSO2 API Manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wso2 calling API's without token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606305/wso2-calling-apis-without-token)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for that you need to set `Auth Type` to `None` for API resources as explined in http://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/disabling-oauth-in-api-cloud/

Duplicate: [wso2 calling API's without token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606305/wso2-calling-apis-without-token)

Comment: Yes it works!! Thank you.  But what is the security for API if Auth type is NONE and How about the throttling in this case? Is this works in Prod env as well?

Comment: If the authorization type is none, some things are not working (such as statistics),  but I believe some throttling is still effective (if you specify TPS). However for full throttling of not-authenticated client you need to define your own policy [see the docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+New+Throttling+Policies) or there's a way through the governance configuration (I'd need to seach  for that)